# Left outer join and inner join on multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join, outer-join

I need to replicate following where condition in Oracle to mysql.. I have also written my version of mysql query and I am having trouble writing left outer join part (I need to perform left outer on voters and join with nodes. Can someone please help?

**Oracle equivalent:**

```
WHERE B.nid=C.nid
AND B.uid = D.uid
and D.nid(+)= E.nid
```

**Mysql query**

```
select 
C.ccc
,D.dewde
from
USERS B
inner join
 ACCOUNT_GROUP_INFO C on (B.nid = C.nid)
  inner join
VOTERS D on (B.uid = D.uid)
 left outer join
 NODES E on (D.nid = E.nid)
```

Can someone please help me with the query?

Comment: Did you ran your current query? What's the issue you find?

Comment: Also, what might the "correct" output look like?

Comment: my current query i believe is doing an outer join on nodes tables, whereas i need to do an left outer join on voters. I am not sure about the correct syntax for that

Comment: Can someone please help???? I really need help writing this query